# Given $z$ show that $\left | z\right | = 2\sin\theta$ and $\arg z = \theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been attempting this complex-related question but couldn't quite crack the challenge.

> (b) Given that $$z={1-\cos 4\theta+i\sin 4\theta\over\sin 2\theta+2i\cos^2\theta},$$ show that $|z|=2\sin\theta$ and $\arg z=\theta$.

I've attempted various routes such as using basic trigonometric identities and De Moivre's Theorem however neither make me feel I'm getting closer to the answer (if anything, getting further).

I do appreciate hints that guide me on how to solve it rather than simply jotting down the answer (you're more than welcome to do so either way).

Comment: Have you tried splitting $z$ up into its real and imaginary parts?

Comment: @Bob1123 - Just tried that, I get two fractions but don't seem to simplify further (going to keep trying down that road though)

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$z=\frac{2 \sin^2{2 \theta} + i 2 \sin{2 \theta} \cos{2 \theta}}{2 \cos{\theta} (\sin{\theta}+i \cos{\theta})} = 2 \sin{\theta} \frac{\sin{2 \theta} + i \cos{2 \theta}}{\sin{\theta}+i \cos{\theta}} = 2 \sin{\theta} \frac{i e^{-i 2 \theta}}{i e^{-i \theta}}$$

I get $|z|=2 \sin{\theta}$ but $\arg{z} = -\theta$.

Comment: Sigh, I had this question going on for a whole page..